# VueJs - Need to bring a linear progress bar when a record is saved

Tags: vue.js, progress-bar, vuetify.js

I need to show a linear progress bar  when a save button is clicked. The progress bar needs to update on each time interval and after completion it needs to be hide.

Added vue component

```
<template>
<div class="components" :key="documentComponentkey">
    <!--Document Version History Component-->
    <DocumentHistoryComponents></DocumentHistoryComponents>
    <!--Generic Header Component-->
    <HeaderComponents></HeaderComponents>
    <div class="components-sub-container">           
        <!--Generic Form Component-->
        <BodyComponents></BodyComponents>
    </div>
    <!--Generic Footer Component-->
    <FooterComponents></FooterComponents>
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLx6W.png)

Comment: try this out
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-linear/#query-indeterminate-and-determinate

Comment: i have given like this:  <HeaderComponents></HeaderComponents>
        <div class="components-sub-container">
            <!--Progress Linear Component-->
        <v-progress-linear value="progressBarValue" v-if="loading" class="form-progress-linear document" :indeterminate="true"></v-progress-linear>
        <div style="height:20px;"></div>
            <!--Generic Form Component-->
            <BodyComponents></BodyComponents>
        </div>. But I am not getting linear bar when saving record

Comment: can't help you without knowing what is your script logic. Some example in codesandbox would be helpful.

Comment: <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent  min-width="350" max-width="600" hide-overlay > <v-card><v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2"> {{ title }} </v-card-title> <v-card-text><p></p> <h3>{{ message }}</h3> </v-card-text><v-spacer></v-spacer><v-card-actions><v-spacer></v-spacer> <v-progress-linear            indeterminate color="blue" class="mb-0"         width="100%" /> </v-card-actions> </v-card> <v-card> </v-card> </v-dialog>

Comment: the progress bar is not updating

Answer (score 0):

```html
<v-progress-linear v-if=true indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
```

Try changing the prop indeterminate as in snippet. The progress bar display depends on V-if evaluation. If Your v-if results in true, the progress bar will be displayed and will have continuously animation of progress.
If v-if results in false you will not see the progress bar . So set v-if when save is complete (may be once you get a signal from backend if you have set up that way).